# Repeating rstan::stan() by parallel calculation

Tags: stan

I try to validate the model. 
I replicate the estimates by `rstan::stan()`.

Each fitting is not related each other and thus in principle, it probably possible to calculate by parallel.

Is there such package to calculate `rstan::stan()` by parallel for independent many datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Expanding on that answer, you can use the parallel processing facilities of R to set up many calls.  If you want to use the same model for each one, compile the Stan program using `stan_model()` and then replace the call to `stan()` with a call to `sampling()`.  That'll avoid recompilation.  We generally recommend using CmdStan for large-scale computing as it doesn't have the memory overhead of R and there's less to go wrong with I/O, system crashes, etc.  Then you can spread out easily over multiple machines.

Also, each chain will run in parallel if you follow the instructions you get when using `library(rstan)`.

Comment: Thank you for reply !! Today I can change from `stan()` to the pair of `stan_model()` and `sampling()` !! In `stan()`, variable `model_name` are used, but in  `sampling()`, variable `object` is used instead. I did not notice this.